# How can the same onClick action be handled in multiple fragments without duplicating code?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick, android-arrayadapter

I'm contributing to my first large project and am struggling with a design decision. I have two fragments that populate a ListView and set a custom ArrayAdapter. Let's say the list items are emails, and the two Fragments are MessageListFragment and SearchMessagesFragment. The ArrayAdapter uses a ViewHolder pattern to inflate each message and attach an onClickListener to the "star" icon.

Now, regardless of which fragment I am in, I want the onClickListener to do the same basic thing: change the status of the email on the server to "starred," and determine if the email needs its position moved in the list (i.e. left alone if there are no filters, moved the to top/bottom if the emails are sorted by starred messages, or removed from the current list if the filter is only non-starred messages).

How can I create this behavior in a reusable manner so that I do not have to repeat this code in both fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you need to perform an action triggered by one of the Fragments or both or further ones you should create an Interface ie:

```
interface MyCustomAction {
  void triggerAction(boolean isTriggered);
}
```

Assign it to the Fragments and implementing it in the Activity responsible of Fragments

Declare Action in the Fragment:

```
private MyCustomAction myCustomAction;
```

Expose method to be assigned by Activity in the Fragment:

```
public void assignAction(MyCustomAction myCustomAction) {
    this.myCustomAction = myCustomAction;
}
```

In the Fragment, when an onClickListner() is called, do that:

```
myCustomAction.triggerAction(true); //or False or what you want...
```

...and in the Activity:

```
myFragment.assignAction(new MyCustomAction() {
    @Override
    public void triggerAction(boolean isTriggered) {
        //Doing something can be triggered by any Fragments using the same Interface
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a separate class, which implements *View.OnClickListener* , and then pass an instance of that class to the *setOnClickListener(...)* method.

Comment: How would that class get access to the fragments' current filters or sorts (i.e. by starred, excluding starred, including starred), to determine what action to take on the sorting and filtering of the list?

Comment: Make the class have a constructor which receives them as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure I fully understand you, are you saying that you have two onClickListeners and you want them to do the same thing without repeated code? If so, you can simply put the repetitious code in a subroutine and call it from both listeners. However if you mean that you have one onClickListener and you want it to listen for two different actions, then you can change those actions so that they act on the same listener. I am not sure what language you are using so I could not tell you how to do this but it should be fairly simple.